# How can I upgrade sqlite3 to at least 3.4.2 (or newer)?

Tags: 8.04, build, gcc

When I try to run `sudo apt-cache showpkg sqlite3`, I only get the version 3.4.2. I need later than that to compile the sqlite3-ruby gem, and I can't make from source files (even with a `./configure --prefix=/usr/bin`, then a `make`, then a `sudo make install`.

Is there a guide or a way to manually `apt-get remove sqlite3` and compile the latest source ([3.6.7.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3/3.7.6.2-1ubuntu1), as found here for Ubuntu) so I can get `sqlite3 -version` up above 3.4.2?!

I've been hunting all around the web, to no avail.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using? the later versions of ubuntu support upto 3.7.4 - ubuntu natty

Comment: Ubuntu 8.04 LTS

Comment: you have a similar question here - why the bounty on this question?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/46286/how-do-i-finish-the-installation-of-a-program-from-source

Comment: Does anybody know a SQLite 3.7.11 PPA for Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an untrusted PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~r0lf/+archive/ppa) with version 3.5.9 of SQLite.

Note - as all PPAs - they are not from canonical so I cant vouch for their authenticity.

However his stable PPA comment is

"To give you a bit of confidence in this PPA, I'd like to point out that I'm an official Debian Maintainer with upload rights to the Debian distribution itself."

Comment: Quite a reliable comment! Saw this, years later.

Comment: @fossfreedom can you update the link of PPA, please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, simply downloaded the latest sqlite3 binary from https://sqlite.org/download.html and `sudo cp ~/Downloads/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3` and I was all set.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite version 3.4.2 can be found here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+source/sqlite3 along with its dependencies and package versions (amd64, i386, etc..)

To install just go to the page and download the package that is for your arquitecture.
then just `dkpg -i PACKAGE.deb`.

for the dependencies (If it gives you any problem about them) do the same. Download from the page and dpkg them until all dependencies are installed. Then install the sqlite 3.4.2 package.

Will that help?