# How do I finish the installation of a program from source?

Tags: source-code, .profile, sqlite

I compiled sqlite3 from source code, version 3.6.16. I used `--prefix=/usr/bin` as my only compiling option.

The binaries compiled and installed correctly, but at the directory `/usr/bin/sqlite3/bin`. So the application sits at `/usr/bin/sqlite3/bin/sqlite3`.

Now, how do I "tell Linux" that sqlite3 is installed to there? So when I run `which sqlite3` it would print `/usr/bin/sqlite3/bin/sqlite3`?

I need this version specifically of `sqlite3` for compiling a RubyGem; `sqlite3-ruby`, v1.3.0 or higher.

I assume I will be adding a `PATH` or something to my `~/.profile` and then running `source .profile` to reload the changes. What is "telling Linux" where applications are installed to called? `symlinks`?

Comment: I think the title needs moderation, because I didn't know what else to call it, but it's vague and ambiguous. I don't know what to call this problem! lol

Comment: I would recommend calling it something like "need alias or symlink for install path" but I'm not sure that's any easier. I flagged the post, so that hopefully a mod will look at it and perhaps edit the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when compiling source, I would use something similar to the following:

```
--prefix=/usr
```

I suspect that this will put everything where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Try editing `~/.bashrc` to include this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/sqlite3/bin/
```

Another way of doing without modifying the path is to create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/sqlite3/bin/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```

Be aware that if you've installed `sqlite3`'s package, its executable file will conflict with your newly compiled version. You're going to have to run `/usr/bin/sqlite3/bin/sqlite3` explicitly.

BTW, using `--prefix=/usr/bin` as a compiling option is not a very good idea, I would recommend `--prefix=/usr/local` instead.